# Listing all cardano tokens using cardano db sync

Tags: cardano-db-sync

I am currently starting out with cardano db sync and wanted to ask if it is possible to obtain all native and nft tokens and their metadata using cardano db sync? could someone guide me? I can't seem to find sufficient resources for beginner like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the ma_tx_mint and ma_tx_out tables to utxo_view. This will only get you the policyid and asset name (hex encoded) for an asset though and you need to query the metadata server to get any other information about the tokens.